# Before Updating jquery-ui 1.12.1 to 1.13.2, do I need to update jquery version as well

Tags: html, jquery, web, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js in my project. I tried to update the jquery-ui version from 1.12.1 to 1.13.2.
After updating the version the application is not working as expected (console errors).
The jquery version we are using is jquery-3.5.1.min.js.
Do I need to update the jquery version as well?

Comment: No you should not need to but I would recommend that also since there are no expected compatibility issues and some great updates re: https://blog.jquery.com/2023/05/11/jquery-3-7-0-released-staying-in-order/  ref the release notes https://blog.jqueryui.com/category/releases/  Either way it might help with some HTML and code the reproduces your issue - AND please post the errors as text so we don't have to just guess or close this as needing details.

Comment: May i know how did you upgrade jquery-ui version, even i am trying same at my end, but i couldn't able to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jQuery UI release notes](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.13/) from last year, the minimal supported version of jQuery is now 1.8

So the answer is no.

I would today, 12th of July 2023 still upgrade to 3.7.0 from May 11, 2023